# Meta query - How to display a null meta key

Tags: meta-query

At the base I have this query wich displays 9 randoms custom post type :

```
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'adverts',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term
        )
    )
);
```

Now I would like to display 9 adverts (CPT) which have a votes average (meta_key) lower than 6. So I add this :

```
$args= array(
    'post_type' => 'adverts',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'posts_per_page' => 9,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key' => 'votes_average',
           'value' => '6',
           'compare' => '<',
           'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
        )
    )
);
```

When I don't add this meta_query, my first query works. I mean it diplays random posts even those who have a "votes_average" equal to 0. But the secondary query doesn't display the adverts with a "votes_average" equal to 0.

Did I forget something ?

Answer (score 7):

Finally, this meta_query works :

```
'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
               'key' => 'votes_average',
               'value' => '6',
               'compare' => '<',
               'type'    => 'NUMERIC',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'votes_average',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                'value' => 'null',
            )
        ),
```

Comment: thanks for sharing, works like a charm, indeed! (mind the comma's after 'numeric' and 'null' though...)

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing your answer. Works like a charm.